# php curl not saving file to location

Tags: php, curl, laravel

I have been searching for an answer for this all day, but with no luck!

I want to download/copy an image from the web to a location on my server, The code below doesn't seam to throw any errors other than the image is just not saving to the required  or any directory.

As you can see I am using cURL to get the image and the variable $contents is returning true (1) so I am assuming the script works but I am actually missing something.

### Many thanks in advance for your help. :-)

```
    $dir = URL::base() . "/img/products/";

    $imgSrc = "an image on the web";

    $file = fopen($dir, "wb");

    $headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';              
    $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';         
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';         
    $user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)';  

    $ch = curl_init($imgSrc);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);         
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);         
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file); // location to write to
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
    $contents = curl_exec($ch);
    $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($lfile);

    if ($curl_errno > 0) 
    {
        Log::write("CURL", "cURL Error (".$curl_errno."): ".$curl_error);
    } 
    else 
    {
        Log::write("CURL", "Data received: " . $contents);
    }

    return;
```

Comment: You aren't specifying a proper filename... Only the directory path exists in $dir.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I changed to this: $file = fopen($dir . basename($imgSrc), "wb"); But I get the same result.

Comment: Changed to an absolute path: $file = fopen("http://domain.co.uk/img/products/newfilename.jpg", "wb"); Still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally got it all working and here is the code if anyone else ever tries to do the same sort of thing!

I was missing these parts:

```
    $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/img/products/";
```

and

```
    fwrite($file,$contents);
```

So here is my final code... credit to Sébastien for pointing me in the right direction. Thanks.

```
        if($method == 'save')
        {
            $productId = Input::get('pId');
            $removeProductImages = DB::table('product_ref_images')->where('product_id', '=', $productId)->delete();

            $imagesData = Input::get('imageRefs');

            $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/img/products/";

            $sortOrder = 0;

            for ($i=0; $i < count($imagesData); $i++) {

                $imgSrc = trim($imagesData[$i]['imgSrc']);
                $imgId = trim($imagesData[$i]['imgId']);

                $file = fopen($dir . basename($imgSrc), "wb");

                $headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';              
                $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';         
                $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';         
                $user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)';  

                $ch = curl_init($imgSrc);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);         
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);         
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
                $contents = curl_exec($ch);
                $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
                $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
                curl_close($ch);

                if ($curl_errno > 0) 
                {
                    Log::write("CURL", "cURL Error (".$curl_errno."): ".$curl_error);
                    break;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    fwrite($file,$contents);
                    fclose($file);

                    $imageIds = DB::table('product_ref_images')->order_by('image_id', 'desc')->first();

                    if($imageIds == null)
                    {
                        $imageIds = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $imageIds = $imageIds->image_id;
                    }

                    $updateImages = DB::table('product_ref_images')
                        ->insert(array(
                            'image_id'          =>  $imageIds + 1,
                            'product_id'        =>  $productId,
                            'flickr_image_id'   =>  $imgId,
                            'sort_order'        =>  $sortOrder++,
                            'local_storage_url' =>  $dir . basename($imgSrc),
                            'created_at'        =>  date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                            'updated_at'        =>  date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
                    ));
                }
            }
            return Response::json('Complete');
        }
```

Comment: This would be a more helpful answer if you removed the application specific parts e.g. inserting images into your database, and the answer comprised the specific code which solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Provide the file the writing access to PHP FILE using curl to store the contents. This can be done in three ways:

- If you have the terminal access then use chmod to provide the writing access
- If you have the CPanel access then use directory explorer then provide the writing access to the file by changing file properties.
- You must have the access to FTP and change the file access attributes and provide the writing access.

Comment: I have made sure that the directory permissions are set to 777 via cpanel

Answer (score 0):

Don't use curl.

If all you need to do is download an image, go for "file_get_contents" instead.
It's dead easy:

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png");
File::put('where/to/store/the/image.jpg', $fileContents);
```

Comment: Agreed this is a lot easier, however cURL is more customisable and faster.

Comment: interesting, just added your code, get the following failed to open stream: No such file or directory, looking at the 'Stack Trace' in laravel it looks like it trying to put the files outside the public folder but I cannot see exactly where?

Comment: You can specify where the image should be saved by changing "where/to/store/the/image.jpg" to the path+filename of your liking.

Ben is correct, if speed matters, you might want to mess around with curl's (horrible API) after all.

Comment: :-) Yep, its been a long day!

Answer (score 0):

```
function saveImageToFile($image_url,$output_filename)
{
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $raw=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($saveto))
    {
        unlink($saveto); //Saves over files
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is quite simple, and I have no idea how everyone else ignored it. It is Laravel-specific. Your $dir variable returns an HTTP resource identifier. What you need is a **filesystem** identifier.

For laravel, change your URL::to() to path("public") to tell Laravel to stop using HTTP URIs and instead take the local path to the public folder (/your/laravel/setup/path/public/).

**code**

```
$dir = path("public") . "img/products/";

$imgSrc = "an image on the web";

$file = fopen($dir . substr($imgSrc,strrpos("/",$imgSrc)+1), "wb");

$headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';              
$headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';         
$headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';         
$user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)';  

$ch = curl_init($imgSrc);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file); // location to write to
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
$curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
$curl_error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($curl_errno > 0) 
{
    Log::write("CURL", "cURL Error (".$curl_errno."): ".$curl_error);
} 
else 
{
    Log::write("CURL", "Data received: " . $contents);
    fwrite($file,$contents);
    fclose($file);

}

return;
```

Comment: I kind of understand, but obviously not quite! :-) $dir = URL::to('public') . "/img/products/"; or $dir = URL::to('home/servername/public_html/img/products/');

Comment: Drop the url::to completely. I'll edit my answer in a second with the code.

Comment: Edited with some code. I've taken the opportunity to actually add an `fwrite` call. The `substr` I added is aimed at getting the filename from an URL.

Comment: Thanks for this Sébastien, substr didn't work for me but basename() is fine in my case & works well. I can now save files, but for some reason only on my development macachine, when I run it on the production server I get a stream error: fopen(/img/products/php.gif): failed to open stream: No such file or directory...I must have an error in Laravel on the production site or the way it has been uploaded... My core Laravel path constant is set to '../apps/dhg/paths.php'; so it's outside the public_html folder and the path to the public directory is set to $paths['public'] = 'public';

Comment: I changed the path to the public directory to $paths['public'] = 'public'; but the files did not save, so I changed my $dir to the absolute path on the server and everything now works as i had hoped!

Comment: The main problem now is that dev and production sites are not the same.

Comment: You're going to struggle with that one. Why don't you use a network-mounted folder?

Comment: If you are on linux, you can use nfs, samba or equivalent to mount a remote folder. This will allow you to have a network drive shared across both servers, which you could use for uploads.  This might help you: http://www.centos.org/docs/4/html/rhel-sag-en-4/s1-nfs-mount.html .

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

You're storing the response to a file, not to the return variable.  Otherwise, you have to save it yourself (like you did in the other solution).